# ActiveSync folder sync issues following import from IMAP

Tags: exchange-2007, imap, activesync

Currently we're running a Microsoft Exchange 2007 server on Windows Server 2008, with which we don't really have any particular issues with ActiveSync normally.

In this case we've onboarded a new client who were using Gmail. We downloaded their emails via IMAP, exported them to .PST files and imported them into Exchange.

Everything is working fine, with the exception that these folders do not appear on phones syncing using ActiveSync. They do appear in OWA and Outlook.

We've tried using MFCMAPI to change the folder class (tag 0x3613001E) to IPF.Note from IPF.Mapi but this hasn't made a difference.

Newly created folders will sync to the phones with no issues whatsoever. We can manually export IMAP folders then import them into newly created folders in Outlook, but obviously this isn't an ideal solution as there are dozens of users with complex folder hierarchies.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and if so, how did you allow these folders to appear on smartphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up writing a PowerShell script to export all the folders, re-create them, then reimport them. Not really an ideal solution, but it did accomplish what we needed.

After we did this we had to re-add the accounts to mobile devices to get the folders to appear.

More of a workaround, but this did solve the problem.